# nested dom-repeat displays nothing

Tags: polymer, dom-repeat

I'm trying to do a nested dom-repeat, I don't have any error but still I have an empty display. Inspecting the elements I can see that data is actually there and also the page shows something for a very short time before going blank. Below, an excerpt of the code:

```
     <iron-ajax auto url="http://localhost:8808/datal2" handle-as="json" last-response="{{top}}"></iron-ajax>

     <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{top.top}}" as="item">
       <div>
         <span id="l4-support-offering-[[index]]">{{item.l2}}</span>
       </div>


       <iron-ajax auto url="[[computeCompleteUrl(item.l2)]]" handle-as="json" last-response="{{top}}"></iron-ajax>

        <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{top.top}}" as="level24" index-as="indexl24">
          <div>
            <span id="l4-support-offering-l4[[indexl24]]">{{level24.l4}}</span>
          </div>
        </template>
     </template>

    <script>

    ........
      properties: {
    top: {
      type: Array,
      value: function() { return []; }
    },
    level24: {
      type: Array,
      value: function() { return []; }
    },
    ................
```

Polymer is v 1.8.0

I changed the code:

```
 <p>
  Hello!
</p>
<iron-ajax auto url="http://localhost:8808/datal2" handle-as="json" last-response="{{lev2}}"></iron-ajax>


     <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{lev2.top}}" as="iteml2">
         <span id="l4-support-offering-[[index]]">{{iteml2.l2}}</span><br>

     <iron-ajax auto url="[[computeCompleteUrl(iteml2.l2)]]" handle-as="json" last-response="{{lev4}}"></iron-ajax>
            <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{lev4.l4byl2}}" as="level4" index-as="indexl24">
                <span id="l4-support-offering-l4[[indexl24]]">{{level4.l4}}</span>

            </template><br>


</template>
 <script>
Polymer({
  is: 'game',

  properties: {
    lev2: {
      type: Array,
      value: function() { return []; }
    },
    lev4: {
      type: Array,
      value: function() { return []; }
    }
  },

  computeCompleteUrl: function(level) {
    return 'http://localhost:8808/datal4byl2/' + level;
    console.log("manager is:" +level);
  },
```

Now I have something displayed but it's not correct. I have something like

X 
1,2,3,4
 Y
1,2,3,4
 Z
1,2,3,4

while it should be (this is just an example)

X 
8,2,4
Y
6,8,5,2
Z
1,2,3,4

so it's always populated with the data of the last element from the first list.

Answer (score 0):

You are referencing to `top.top` but this variable does not exists. Your `top` property is type of `Array` so you can't do `top.top`. First, you have to iterate throught `top` property and then in nested `dom-repeat` - `item.top` (maybe you just wrongly copied your code)

Comment: I changed the code so maybe now is little bit more clear. Now I get data on screen but for each element in the first loop I have same second elements (corresponding to the last element of the first loop). So it's something like: X(1,2,3,4), Y(1,2,3,4),Z(1,2,3,4) while it should be X(1,3,4), Y(6,8,5,2),Z(9).

Comment: please see my changes.

Comment: @vlucian but still the same.. you are refenrencing to `lev2.top` but `lev2` is Array. so how can javascript access `lev2.top` its nonsense. Plus it would be nice if you added example of those array and their structure. Otherwise i can't help you more when you have so many mistakes in your example code

Comment: first is like this: {"top":[{"l4":"Name name","score":1100,"teamgr":"depart","oldscore":1200},... second one is similar: {"l4byl2":[{"l4":"name name","score":1350,"teamgr":"depart","oldscore":1350},... . I'm using same code to display in separate pages everything from the http://localhost:8808/datal2 or http://localhost:8808/datal4byl2 and it's working fine like this,nesting them seems to be dificult.

Comment: @vlucian mm. I have no idea what is wrong. everything seems ok. the only thing that may cause the problem, but I am not really sure is that you are using numbers in your variables.. ( i have never tested this) so I don't really know. Try to simplify your code as much as possible. try to hardcode your variables, try to set extremely light arrays, remove unnecessary html code and so on

Answer (score 0):

In the end it worked after I change the second dom-repeat to:

```
 <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{getLevelFours(item.l2)}}"  as="level24" index-as="indexl24">
```

and the functions used:

```
 computeCompleteUrl: function(level) {
     return 'http://localhost:8808/datal4byl2/' + level;
  },
 getLevelFours: function(level) {
     let theUrl = this.computeCompleteUrl(level);
     // http request based on url
     var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
     xmlHttp.open( "GET", theUrl, false ); // false for synchronous request
     xmlHttp.send( null );
     var myjson = JSON.parse(xmlHttp.responseText)
     return myjson.l4byl2;
```